# Settings button on toolbar crash application

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

2 days is the current time i am trying to solve this, and still no solution, basicly i created a simple navigation drawer, that has a toolbar, float action button and a navigation(the default activity from android studio).

After that i tried to change it a bit and i edited the icon from it on the styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/nephritis</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/emerald</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_user</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

i think i did some change that destroyed my toolbar, so basicly i am including the toolbar and some other things to my main acitivty like this:

my Main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_plant_feed"
        app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="8%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="0%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="0%" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_plant_feed"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_plant_feed_drawer"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**then i have the included layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.PlantFeed">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/emerald"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="#f1c40f"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_plant_feed" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**my activity class:**

```
public class PlantFeed extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,PlantFeedAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    //initialize fields

    String token;

    ArrayList<PlantPhotoUser> photos = new ArrayList<>();

    VolleyService mVolleyService;
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    final String GETREQUEST = "GETCALL";

    String connectionTxt;

    String URL;

    String date;
    String lat;
    String lon;
    String alt;

    PlantFeedAdapter plantFeedAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_plant_feed);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        connectionString connection = ((connectionString) getApplicationContext());
        connectionTxt = connection.getGlobalVarValue();

        URL = connectionTxt + "/fotos";


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(PlantFeed.this,CameraCapture.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleView2);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        plantFeedAdapter = new PlantFeedAdapter(getApplicationContext(), photos,PlantFeed.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(plantFeedAdapter);

        token = checkForToken();

        initVolleyCallback();

        mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);

        mVolleyService.getDataVolley(GETREQUEST,URL,token);

    }

    void initVolleyCallback(){
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType,JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("HELLL","hi1");
            }

            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
                PlantPhotoUser plantPhotoUser;
                Log.d("HELLLL","hi");
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("objeto",object.toString());

                        int userId = object.getInt("userId");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(userId));
                        String username = object.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(username));
                        int plantId = object.getInt("plantId");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(plantId));
                        String specie = object.getJSONObject("plant").getString("specie");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(specie));

                        String path = object.getString("image");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(path));
                        int fotoId = object.getInt("id");

                        if(object.getString("date") != null){
                            date = object.getString("date");
                        }

                        if(object.getString("lat") != null){
                            lat = object.getString("lat");
                        }

                        if(object.getString("lon") != null){
                            lon = object.getString("lon");
                        }

                        if(object.getString("altitude") != null){
                            alt = object.getString("altitude");
                        }

                        plantPhotoUser = new PlantPhotoUser(fotoId,plantId,userId,path,specie,date,lat,lon,alt,username);
                        photos.add(plantPhotoUser);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                plantFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("FAIL",error.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    public String checkForToken() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String tokenKey = getResources().getString(R.string.token);
        String token = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.token), tokenKey); // take the token
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.plant_feed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            Intent i = new Intent(PlantFeed.this,CameraCapture.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            Intent i = new Intent(PlantFeed.this,PlantFeed.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Intent i = new Intent(PlantFeed.this,FamilyLibrary.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRowClick(int position, String name, int id, View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTitleClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,PhotosForPlant.class);
        i.putExtra("plantId",String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,PhotosForPlant.class);
        i.putExtra("plantId",String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReportClicked(int position, int id, String name, View clickedview) {
        Log.d("HELLLO","HELLOO");
        showDialogReport(id,name);
    }



    @Override
    public void onUserIconClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,UserProfile.class);
        i.putExtra("userId",id);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUsernameClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,UserProfile.class);
        i.putExtra("userId",id);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAvaliationClicked(int position, int id, String name, View clickedview) {

    }


    private void showDialogReport(int id, String name) {
        Log.d("HELLLO","HELLOO");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlantFeed.this);
        builder.setTitle(name);
        builder.setMessage("Tem a certeza que pretende reportar a fotografia?");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //TODO reportar base de dados
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

**finally the menu layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

i want to show the menu, but it never shows, it crashes before, and i get this stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android, PID: 12537
                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView.setTitle(ListMenuItemView.java:127)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView.initialize(ListMenuItemView.java:113)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:100)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:153)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:803)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

i don't have any activity with those names on stacktrace, they exist because the navigation created them internaly so i don't know how to avoid this error, any help?

**adapter code:**

```
package com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.R;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.modelView.PlantPhotoUser;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by FilipeCosta on 29/05/2017.
 */

public class PlantFeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlantFeedAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onRowClick(int position, String name, int id, View view);
        void onTitleClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview);
        void onImageClicked(int position,int id, View clickedview);
        void onReportClicked(int position, int id,String name, View clickedview);
        void onUserIconClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview);
        void onUsernameClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview);
        void onAvaliationClicked(int position, int id,String name, View clickedview);

    }

    private ArrayList<PlantPhotoUser> photos;
    private Context context;

    public PlantFeedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PlantPhotoUser> photos, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.photos = photos;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public PlantFeedAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.plant_feed_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PlantFeedAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.name.setText(photos.get(i).getSpecie());
        viewHolder.username.setText(photos.get(i).getUsernName());
        viewHolder.data.setText(photos.get(i).getDate().split("T")[0]);
        Log.d("data123",(photos.get(i).getDate().toString()));

        String urlFoto = "http://fe1b7efd.ngrok.io/" + photos.get(i).getPath();

        if(urlFoto.toLowerCase().contains("public/")){
            urlFoto = urlFoto.replace("public/","");
        }

        viewHolder.userIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onUserIconClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), photos.get(i).getUserId(), view);
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onUsernameClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),photos.get(i).getUserId(), view);
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.plantImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onImageClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), photos.get(i).getIdPlant(), view);
                }
            }
        });


        viewHolder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onTitleClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),photos.get(i).getIdPlant(),v);
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.reportImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onReportClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),photos.get(i).getIdPlant(),photos.get(i).getSpecie(),v);
                }
            }
        });

        /*viewHolder.avaliationFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onAvaliationClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),photos.get(i).getIdPlant(),photos.get(i).getSpecie(),v);
                }
            }
        });*/



        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(urlFoto)
                .resize(300, 300)
                .into(viewHolder.plantImg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView name;
        private ImageView userIcon;
        private TextView avaliationFoto;
        private ImageView plantImg;
        private ImageView foto;
        private TextView username;
        private ImageView reportImage;
        private TextView data;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            data = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.data);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.plantName);
            userIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.userIcon);
            plantImg = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.plantPhoto);;
            username = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.password);
            reportImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cameraForbiden);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: The ``TextView`` is ``null``.

Comment: Can u post this adapter code  PlantFeedAdapter  I think problem with this adapter

Comment: updated the PlantFeedAdapter

Comment: what textView is null?

Comment: @FilipeCosta do you have your project on github or somewhere I will take a look?

Comment: sorry yupi would love to share, but it is a private project :/

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: sorry, you are right, but i can't solve this issue, the problem can't be on the plant feed row since that layout is the row of my container, the problem is on the toolbar :S

Comment: Having same problem here. I don't consider this is duplicated with a generic "Null pointer question". I changed no code and started getting this nullpointer when clicking the menu. Traces are all from support library, not from my code.

Comment: I found that my problem appeared by upgrading this dependency: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0' to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'. Downgrading to 25.3.0 fixes the problem.